# Control 0-1 VDC with ESP32/PIC

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, pic, esp32

I would like to create a circuit to vary DC voltage between 0 and 1 V in 0.001 V increments. I want a constant voltage output, not PWM.

I am versed in ESP32 and PIC processors,  but I’m having a mental block on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use PWM and filter it (slow response,  possible ripple) or attach a DAC aka Digital to Analog Converter (at least 10 bit) to the ESP32. You could even use a digital pot with adequate resolution and maybe a buffer amplifier.

Any of those possible solutions might require an op-amp and a few resistors (and possibly an external reference chip) to get right, but the details depend on the requirements such as speed and accuracy/stability.

An example of a DAC is the I2C Microchip [MCP4725](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MSLD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP4725-Data-Sheet-20002039E.pdf). It uses the power supply voltage as a reference and is 12-bit so you could simply throw away some of the resolution and use 0 to 0x4D8 (resolution a bit better than 1mV with a 3.3V supply). There are many other DACs on the market, so you should do an evaluation if you choose to go that way. That particular one shows up in hobbyist contraptions. Of course without a reference (internal or external) the unadjusted output voltage will be no more accurate or stable than the power supply voltage.